# What does this Latin phrase, from an ancient astrology wheel say?

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, ancient-greek

"Hemphta - Numen Triforme" the greek portion reads "παντόλιoφoν"

I think it says something like the "holy trinity" or "godhead trinity" but thats just based on googling around.

[image]

Comment: I would not characterize this image as "ancient", Kircher's work was published in 1652–54.

Comment: The image is much older than the publication.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Hemphta* is the name of the deity.

The Latin *Numen triforme* means “threefold deity,” or “god having three forms.”

The Greek actually appears to say παντόμορφον (pantómorphon), which I take to mean “all-formed” or something to that effect.

The image (specifically the right version) is from Athanasius Kircher's [Oedipus Aegyptiacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus_Aegyptiacus), a treatise on Egyptology, [volume 2, part 2, p. 160](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Oedipi_Aegyptiaci._t._2,_ps._2_1653_(22596191).jpg) (1653 edition). I am not sure what Kircher's idea of this Egyptian religious concept was exactly, but he writes a little more about it in [part 1, p. 101](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Athanasii_Kircheri_Oedipus_aegyptiacus/t0auSWv5Vy0C?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA101&printsec=frontcover), and if I understand him right, the deity is known as *Hemphta*, *Phta* and *Amun*, and he believes that it is an obscured, imperfect representation of the Holy Trinity of Christian doctrine («Sacrosanctam & ter benedictam Triadem, fidei Christianae mysterium uti maximum, sic sublimissimum, nullo non tempore etiam sub obscuris fabularum figmentis adumbratum esse»).

Comment: According to LSJ, [_παντόμορφος_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpanto%2Fmorfos) is either an alternate form of [_πάμμορφος_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpa%2Fmmorfos) meaning ‘assuming all forms’ (that fits with a god); or an adjective or noun meaning ‘(relating to) the Universe’, which also fits fairly well with a good.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It doesn't mean "relating to the Universe," but it is an adjective that is applied to the universe, which contains within it all forms...or something like that.

Comment: Yes, Kircher tried to translate ancient Egyptian hieroglyphs; [here](https://web.stanford.edu/group/kircher/cgi-bin/site/?attachment_id=757) is his translation of the Minervan obelisk (in Rome), starting with: "Hemphta Numen supremum..."

Comment: Yes, I found it! The rest of the page reads,

"Are you afraid of the zodiac hieroglyphics of Hermes?

Indeed, neither have I until now, met or imagined anyone of my own genius, would bring into this place a hieroglyphic fragment from Gazus, outside the phylactery [a small leather box] of Francis Cardinal Barberinus [the The nephew of Pope Urban VIII], in which whatsoever things concerning the twelve Genius of the Zodiac are discernible, as if looking at a mirror."